# CRM 2011: Subgrid does not include paging when its inside a collapsed tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a CRM subgrid inside a tab, and in my code (JS) I'm using Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("XXX").setDisplayState("collapsed") if the subgrid doesn't contain data.
When I open the tab, the subgrid inside it has only one empty line (instead of filling the tab area although the grid is set to fill the tab) and doesn't have its footer with the paging.
Farther more, when adding records to the subgrid, I can see just the first record(cause its in the first line) and in order to see the rest I have to refresh the form so the tab will remain open.
This happens while closing the tab automatically (via js) and not in case of customizing the tab to be close in the form.
P.s: when resizing the page - the subgrid inside the tab gets fine.

I looked for a solution with no success, Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had to wait until the subgrid is loaded before collapsing the tab.
Thanks to this post : 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmbusiness/archive/2014/02/27/crm-2011-javascript-to-wait-for-a-grid-to-load-and-then-check-for-rows